# Using Rijndael/AES Encryption in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, aes, sqlclr, rijndael

What are some possible and reliable ways to encrypt using Rijndael/AES in T-SQL? 
Or is using and embedded assembly in order to use c# or vb.net in your SQL Project the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into embedding assemblies in sql server. It is possible but you have to install the assemblies housing your code and use the proper syntax to mold the function wrappers.